# Can not limit the number of check boxes to be selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm using foreach loop to generate the checkboxes in my form. It is given below.

```
<?php $index = 0;
foreach($cameramen as $n_key){ ?>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cameramen_<?php echo $index+1; ?>" name="cameramen" class="subscriber" value="<?php echo $index+1; ?>">

            <?php 
                echo $n_key->emplist3; 
                $index++;
            ?>

        </label>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to limit the number of checkboxes to be selected by the user to two.
I used the following javascript function but it not worked(It allows to select all the checkboxes).

```
 $("input[name=cameramen]").change(function(){
    var max= 2;
    console.log($("input[name=cameramen]:checked").length);
    if( $("input[name=cameramen]:checked").length == max ){
        $("input[name=cameramen]").attr('disabled', 'true');
        $("input[name=cameramen]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
         $("input[name=cameramen]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
```

Someone please help me to solve this problem which I have being struggling for hours to solve.

Comment: Although you should use `.prop()`, not `.attr()`, your code should work as i see it. Maybe you bind event before checkboxes are available in DOM. Do you wrap it in ready handler? Or delegate event as proposed by @ntgCleaner below **↓↓↓**

Comment: try using $(document).on('change', 'input[name-cameramen]', function(){...}` Also, tell us how it's not working

Comment: i reproduced your code and it seems to work! are you sure that all input elements got the name attribute "cameraman" ?

Comment: there's also php here. You running this off a web server with php installed and using the proper syntax to use it, as `http://localhost` and not as `file:///`? what does the HTML source reveal, code or parsed php?

Comment: @FalcoB yes name attribute is cameramen for all.

Comment: also, if there are multiple checkboxes being generated, they need to be treated as an array `name="cameramen[]"`

Comment: Check if some other JS is conflicting with this, because I replicated your code & works well here

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa No JS  except this. What kind of conflict can be happen? Still not work for me.

Comment: Then check if your console is throwing an error. JQuery not included etc..

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa No errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  

 $(".cb").on('click', function(e) {
   var count = 0;
   var list = $('.cb');
    
    $('.cb').each(function(i) {
     
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       count++;
      }
      
    });
    
    if(count > 2)
    {
     alert('You cannot check more than 2 checkboxes!');
     $(this).prop('checked', false);
      
      //return false;
    } else {
     return true;
    }
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <input class="cb" type="checkbox">Checkbox 1
  <br />
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox">Checkbox 2
  <br />
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox">Checkbox 3
  <br />
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox">Checkbox 4

</div>
```

Hope this helps!